# Finding corresponding word from array to match the a word from another array

Tags: c#

I worded this question really badly I will change the title if I think of a better title

```
 string log1 = this.ReadURL("https://url.com/name1.txt");
            var name1 = log1.Split(',');

            string log2 = this.ReadURL("https://url.com/name2.txt");
            var name2 = log2.Split(',');
```

If I have a textbox equal a word from the name1 array how can I get another textbox to be a the corresponding word from the name2 array

Comment: Find the index in `name1`, lookup the element at that index in `name2`. Check the second array is long enough first so you don't get `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that

Comment: I don't really have time to answer at the moment, but those are things you can research to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok I will try and figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < name1.Length; i++)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == name1[i])
    {
        textbox2.Text = name2[i];
        break;
    }
}
```